# Aggregating monthly data to quarter data

Tags: r, data.table

I want to have a function which converts monthly data to quarter data by taking averages of values. For example :

January 10

February 5

March 15

Then value for the first quarter will be `mean(10,5,15)=10.`

I think I came up with a solution which can solve this problem very easily, but I have small problem with do it in generic way:

```
library(data.table)

date <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2020-04-01'), by = '1 month')
x <- rnorm(244)
df1 <- data.frame(date, x)

aggregate <- function(data){
  setDT(data)
  data[, mean(x), keyby = .(year(date), quarter(date))]
}

aggregate(df1)
```

And in output I get what I want to get. The problem with the function above is that I used 'x' and 'date' in the code above and it's not general. I tried to do it more generic, but I didn't manage to do it. I mean putting instead of 'x' `data[,2]` and instead of 'date' `data[,1]` doesn't work and gives warning in output. I tried to do `unlist(data[,2])` but it gives mean of whole vector instead of certain quarters. Is there any way how can it be more generic ?

Comment: Note that `aggregate()` is already a base function, and it's not a good workflow to mask it over with a custom function.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
agg_quarter <- function(data, datecol, valuecol) {
  setDT(data)
  data[, mean(get(valuecol)), keyby = .(year(get(datecol)), quarter(get(datecol)))]
}
```

Now:

```
agg_quarter(df1, datecol = "date", valuecol = "x")
```

gives:

> ```
>     year quarter           V1
>  1: 2000       1  0.668280150
>  2: 2000       2 -0.432287287
>  3: 2000       3 -0.063654477
>  4: 2000       4 -0.036998919
>  5: 2001       1  0.003495954
> ....
> 78: 2019       2  0.441275470
> 79: 2019       3  0.435215828
> 80: 2019       4  0.561908069
> 81: 2020       1 -0.454111862
> 82: 2020       2 -1.486324939
> ```

---

As per @John's comment, you could make it a single variable function, but that requires that you know wich columns to use beforehand. Probably better is to use default arguments in the function from above:

```
agg_quarter <- function(data, datecol = "date", valuecol = "x") {
  setDT(data)
  data[, mean(get(valuecol)), keyby = .(year(get(datecol)), quarter(get(datecol)))]
}
```

Now you can just use:

```
agg_quarter(df1)
```

If the datacolumn and valuecolumn have other names, you can still use this function. You need to use the function as follows (same as the first part of the answer):

```
agg_quarter(df1, datecol = "other_date", valuecol = "other_x")
```

Comment: Thanks! But there is really no way how to do it by single variable function ?